# Formatting the date in Excel to show current date using Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to format the date value in Access VBA to show the current date on an excel file (for which I'm writing an Access VBA code). However, using Date() hasn't helped (I'm guessing it only works within Access). For example, using Cells(2, 3) = Date() just shows a number "41039", and not the date. I tried Format as well, and that hasn't worked either.
I'm a newbie to Access VBA and would really appreciate any answers to the above question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, a date should appear properly formatted, unless a previous format has been applied.

```
''Requires library reference 
Dim xl As Excel.Application

''Existing instance
Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.application")

xl.Workbooks(1).ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2) = Date
xl.Workbooks(1).ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3) = 30
xl.Workbooks(1).ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

Comment: Thank you Remou. This works great. I did not remember to include it in the activesheet.cells statement and instead just declared the function for the cell (my learning curve hasn't been great lately). But thanks a lot :) 
Have a good day :)